# ASP.NET MVC reading an element's custom html attribute when submitting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit, custom-attributes, html.checkbox

I'm new to ASP.NET and MVC in particular.
Now, I'm trying to understand if I can easily get values of custom attributes of submitted data.

For example, When writing something like this inside a form (which works and posts and I can get the checkbox value)
<%= Html.CheckBox("cb1", new { listen = "listen:6" }) %>

Can I get the value of "listen" directly or do I need JS?
(I know I can just use hidden fields, but I'm I'm asking anyway)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot; when a form is POST-ed, only the name/value pairs are sent. This is a general feature of HTML and forms, and not specific to ASP.NET or MVC.